# How to add event dynamically via UI full calendar

Tags: angularjs, fullcalendar, ui-calendar

I am implementing the UI-calendar in my angular js application. I have successfully added the calendar on the page. But I want to add the event to agendaWeek calendar and save that data into DB.

My code implementation is

```
HTML

<div ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" data-ng-model="eventSources">
                            </div>
```

JS

```
    $scope.eventSources = [];
    $scope.uiConfig = {
        calendar: {
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            height: 450,
            editable: true,
            header: {
                left: '',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'prev,next'
            },
            eventClick: $scope.alertEventOnClick,
            eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
            eventResize: $scope.alertOnResize
        }
    };
```

Please anyone help me to implement the event implementation

Answer (score 0):

You have all the fullcalendar very well described in [the docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/).

You could implement the [eventClick](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/eventClick/) for example like so:

This method is obviously triggered when a user clicks a day in the calendar.
There you create an event source object based on properties you get from the eventClick method.

```
function eventClick(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
    var tempEventSource = {events: [{
        title: calEvent.title,
        start: calEvent.start.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        end: calEvent.end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
        className: calEvent.className[0]
    }]};
    var newEvent = tempEventSource.events[0];
    eventService.saveEvent(newEvent).then(function(event) {
        tempEventSource.events[0].eventid = event.id;
        uiCalendarConfig.calendars['your_calendar'].fullCalendar('addEventSource', tempEventSource);
    });
}
```

Note you get the uiCalendarConfig from injecting it in your controller:

```
function CalendarController(eventService, uiCalendarConfig)
```